# UnicodeDecodeError in sending bytes by socket in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have to send the output of an ipconfig command by using a socket with the check_output method of subprocess. This process used to be easy in python 2.7 but in python 3 everything is more complicated because it shows me a UnicodeDecodeError.

This is the code that sends the bytes:

```
import socket
import subprocess 

client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
client.connect(("localhost",7500))


m = subprocess.check_output('ipconfig')
client.send(m)
```

Of course, it is not necessary to convert bytes to send because the output of check_output already delivers values in bytes format.

But the problem occurs in the receiver since it does not allow to decode it.

The code that receives the data is the following:

```
import socket


serv = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
serv.bind(("localhost",7500))
serv.listen(1)

conex,direccion = serv.accept()
a = conex.recv(4096)
print(a.decode('utf-8'))
```

it shows me the following error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xa2 in position 13: invalid start byte
```

Does anyone know how this could be solved?

Comment: Can you provide the stack trace. Also, you could directly send bytes from the client side. Because your error says that it receives as byte sequence which is not allowed in utf-8 string. Also do `print(type(a))` so that I can get what type is `a`

Comment: *"This process used to be easy in python 2.7 but in python 3 everything is more complicated because it shows me a UnicodeDecodeError."* In other words, you were doing something wrong in python 2 :)

Comment: Actually, I would be very surprised if this exact code worked in Python 2.  I suspect you added the `.decode()` call when converting to Python 3.  If so, then `'utf8'` is probably the wrong encoding (e.g. try `'windows-1252'` or something?).

Comment: What happens if you do `m.decode('utf-8')`? And what's the output of `print(repr(a))`?

Comment: What's your locale encoding (or, if you're on Windows, your OEM codepage) on the client system? (If you have no idea, at least print out `sys.getdefaultencoding()` and put that in the question.) If you take bytes in, say, Latin-1 or UTF-16-LE or Shift-JIS, send them over the network, and then try to decode them as UTF-8, it's going to fail the same way it would if there was no network involved.

Comment: If you really _want_ this to be as easy as Python 2—meaning you print out nonsense mojibake instead of getting an error, which is always harder to spot and harder to debug when you do—you can always do `a.decode('utf-8', 'surrogateescape')`. (Depending on whether you actually have a UTF-8 terminal on the server side, that might give you completely different mojibake than Python 2 did, or the same, or it might magically happen to work if your errors all cancel out, but it won't raise an exception on encoding.)

Answer (score 0):

> in python 3 everything is more complicated because it shows me a
> UnicodeDecodeError.

I know it's a long time but it seem like I had the same issue. II just had to use `conex.recv(4096)` directly without `decode('utf-8')`.

It was just that simple. Just try to print `a` directly:

```
print(a)
```